# Elementor custom Widget addChangeCallback not working

Tags: wordpress, callback, widget, elementor

I created a custom widget and i wanted to force a refresh with `elementor.reloadPreview();` So i tried to use the addChangeCallback handler but it just won't work. My JS Code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(elementor)
    elementor.settings.page.addChangeCallback('text_color', selfUpdate);

})

function selfUpdate(value) {
    console.log("check " + value)
    // elementor.reloadPreview();
}
```

I expected a refresh (or in this case a console.log) after changing the text_color control. I have no idea what's wrong. Any hint where i can find the mistake?

So i tried to add a callback Handler to addChangeCallback. with
`elementor.settings.page.addChangeCallback('text_color', selfUpdate);`

So that every change of "text_color" will trigger the callback

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404351/elementor-live-preview-for-custom-non-elementor-widgets-components but i 'don't see what i do different here